# R bookdown: How to change the title of the table of content for rendering a PDF book

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I am using bookdown to render a PDF book using the documentclass "scrreprt" from koma script. This works so far, however the book is in German
and the table of contents has a title "Contents" instead of a german "Inhaltsverzeichnis".

The "header" of my index.rmd:

```
---
title: "Mein Buchtitel"
author: "Jens Laufer"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
documentclass: scrreprt
---
```

The output of table of contents looks like this:

[image]
I tried also to add a preamble.tex in index.Rmd:

```
---
title: "Mein Buchtitel"
author: "Jens Laufer"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
documentclass: scrreprt
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---
```

preamble.tex

```latex
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
```

However this doesn't help.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variable `toc-title` in the YAML metadata, e.g.,

```
toc-title: "Table of Contents"
```

See the Pandoc Manual for more info: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yihui Xie. What is the recommended way? Doing it with the preamble.tex or with toc-title?

Comment: `toc-title` is more portable since it works for several output formats, but you might only want LaTeX/PDF output, in which case `preamble.tex` is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem by changing the preamble.tex to this:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
```